# Winform contextmenu using c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to use a ContextMenu in Winform application. Please see that it needs to be a ContextMenu and not ContextMenuStrip. The problem with ContextMenu is that I haven't seen any methods or properties to set the font and display an image/icon next to the MenuItem which is easy in case of ContextMenuStrip.

Is it possible to set the font and display an image/icon next to the MenuItem in ContextMenu ?

Comment: Can you explain why not to use ContextMenuStrip ?

Comment: @Asaf I prefer the look and feel of the old ContextMenu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default ContextMenu does not provide this functionality. If you want this functionality, you should create your own custom MenuItem, or you can enable item's [OwnerDraw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menuitem.ownerdraw.aspx) mode and do manual paintings in [DrawItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.menuitem.drawitem.aspx) event handler:

```
var item = new MenuItem("foo");
item.OwnerDraw = true;
item.DrawItem += item_DrawItem;
```

BTW you will also need to handle MeasureItem event to provide size of item which you will draw manually. E.g. creating italic font

```
void item_MeasureItem(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e)
{
    var item = (MenuItem)sender;
    var g = e.Graphics;
    Font font = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Italic);

    e.ItemWidth = 200;
    var size = g.MeasureString(item.Text, font, e.ItemWidth);
    e.ItemHeight = (int)size.Height;            
}

void item_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    var item = (MenuItem)sender;
    var g = e.Graphics;            
    var font = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Italic);
    var brush = new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor);
    g.DrawString(item.Text, font, brush, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y);
}
```

And adding items:

```
ContextMenu = new ContextMenu(new []{new MenuItem("foo"), new MenuItem("bar")});
foreach (MenuItem item in ContextMenu.MenuItems)
{
    item.OwnerDraw = true;
    item.MeasureItem += item_MeasureItem;
    item.DrawItem += item_DrawItem;
}
```

---

Same with custom MenuItem class:

```
public class MenuItemWithItalicFont : MenuItem
{
    private Font font;

    public MenuItemWithItalicFont(string text)
        : base(text)
    {
        OwnerDraw = true;
        font = new Font("Arial", 10, FontStyle.Italic);
    }

    protected override void OnMeasureItem(MeasureItemEventArgs e)
    {
        var g = e.Graphics;
        e.ItemWidth = 200;
        var size = g.MeasureString(Text, font, e.ItemWidth);
        e.ItemHeight = (int)size.Height;
    }

    protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnDrawItem(e);
        var g = e.Graphics;
        var brush = new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor);
        g.DrawString(Text, font, brush, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y);
    }
}
```

Adding items:

```
ContextMenu = new ContextMenu(new []{ 
     new MenuItemWithItalicFont("foo"), 
     new MenuItemWithItalicFont("bar")});
```

---

**NOTE** Actually ContextMenu was replaced by ContextMenuStrip control, and if you need this functionality, then you should use new control. Old ContextMenu is still here mostly for backward compatibility. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenu.aspx):

> ContextMenu is retained for both backward compatibility and future
>   use if you choose.